# Call to private Instamojo\Instamojo::__construct() from context

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, instamojo

```
public function pay(Request $request){

$api = new \Instamojo\Instamojo(
       config('services.instamojo.api_key'),
       config('services.instamojo.auth_token'),
       config('services.instamojo.url')
   );

 try {
   $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
       "purpose" => "FIFA 16",
       "amount" => $request->amount,
       "buyer_name" => "$request->name",
       "send_email" => true,
       "email" => "$request->email",
       "phone" => "$request->mobile_number",
       "redirect_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pay-success"
       ));
        
       header('Location: ' . $response['longurl']);
       exit();
   }catch (Exception $e) {
    print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

> Error after submitting form on  $api = new \Instamojo\Instamojo( line.

Error:- Call to private Instamojo\Instamojo::__construct()

Comment: Instead of creating object via constructor, you'll need to call `init` method as constructor is not `public`. Refer this for usage https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\admin\Instamojo\Instamojo' not found @Haridarshan

Comment: I don't know what you've change but what I meant was to change this `$api = new \Instamojo\Instamojo()` to `$api=\Instamojo\Instamojo::init()`

Comment: I did the same it gives Class 'Instamojo\Exception\InstamojoException' not found error.@Haridarshan

Comment: $api = \Instamojo\Instamojo::init(
      config('services.instamojo.api_key'),
      config('services.instamojo.auth_token'),
      config('services.instamojo.url')
  );     @Haridarshan

Answer (score -2):

Correct usage is like this

```php
$api = \Instamojo\Instamojo::init($authType, [
    'client_id' => '<clientId>',
    'client_secret' => '<clientSecret>',
    'username' => '<userName>',   // optional
    'password' => '<password>',   // optional
    'scope' => '<scope if any>'   // optional
], false);

try {
    $response = $api->createPaymentRequest(array(
        "purpose" => "FIFA 16",
        "amount" => $request->amount,
        "buyer_name" => "$request->name",
        "send_email" => true,
        "email" => "$request->email",
        "phone" => "$request->mobile_number",
        "redirect_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pay-success"
    ));

    header('Location: ' . $response['longurl']);
    exit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

`$authType` can be either `app` or `user`. If you want to use **Test** environment then pass third argument as `true` or `false` for **Production**

**Note:** There is an issue with `Instamojo-php v1.0`. Issue is `InvalidRequestException.php` exception class namespace is not correct. So, fix is to manually change the namespace of this exception class from `Instamojo\Exception` to `Instamojo\Exceptions`

Comment: I tried the same Class it gives 'Instamojo\Exception\InstamojoException' not found

Comment: How you've installed Instamojo-php library and what is the version you're using?

Comment: yes ... i have installed instamojo using composer require instamojo/instamojo-php this  command. version is 1.0

Comment: There is no such file with name InstamojoException.php

Comment: Sorry, I thought that is the issue but just now I've tried it by myself and everything is working fine. Have you changed the method name from `$api->paymentRequestCreate` to `$api->createPaymentRequest`?

Comment: I tried. It gives error-> Class 'Instamojo\Exception\InstamojoException' not found

Comment: Open file `vendor/instamojo/instamojo-php/src/Exceptions/InvalidRequestException.php` and change it's top namespace to `namespace Instamojo\Exceptions;`

Comment: I changed it. It gives "Invalid init type" Error.

Comment: Check `$authType` it should be either **app** or **user**

Comment: It shows "Unauthorized". I don't use Auth. I use session